# Duplicate Foreign Keys Generated in EF6 Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been wrestling with fluent, annotations, and combinations thereof but cannot find out why the following entities and context config generate a migration with duplicate foreign key. I've read all the other posts and tried all the suggested solutions, each one seems to be a different combo of things, but I still cannot get EF to give me a migration with one foreign key. It always generates this extra one.

```
public class REOProperty
{
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyPhotoUrl> PropertyPhotoUrls { get; set; }

    public Guid REOPropertyId { get; set; }

}
public class PropertyPhotoUrl
{
    public Guid REOPropertyId { get; set; }
    public virtual REOProperty REOProperty { get; set; }

    public Guid PropertyPhotoUrlId { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

with context

```
public class REODbContext:DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<REOProperty>()
            .HasKey(a => a.REOPropertyId)
            .Property(a => a.REOPropertyId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyPhotoUrl>()
            .HasKey(a => a.PropertyPhotoUrlId)
            .Property(a => a.PropertyPhotoUrlId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyPhotoUrl>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.REOProperty)
            .WithMany(a=>a.PropertyPhotoUrls)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.REOPropertyId);
    }
}
```

Generates a migration with duplicate foreign keys on the child 
`PropertyPhotoUrl` entity.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.PropertyPhotoUrls",
            c => new
                {
                    PropertyPhotoUrlId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    REOPropertyId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    PhotoUrl = c.String(),
                    REOProperty_REOPropertyId = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PropertyPhotoUrlId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.REOProperties", t => t.REOPropertyId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.REOProperties", t => t.REOProperty_REOPropertyId)
            .Index(t => t.REOPropertyId)
            .Index(t => t.REOProperty_REOPropertyId);
```

I've seen this issue before and usually can resolve by changing up the fluent code. If I try to manual edit the migration to get what I want then the ef throws exceptions when I make queries.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
public class REOProperty
{
    [InverseProperty("REOProperty")]
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyPhotoUrl> PropertyPhotoUrls { get; set; }

    public Guid REOPropertyId { get; set; }

}

public class PropertyPhotoUrl
{
    public Guid REOPropertyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("REOPropertyId")]
    [InverseProperty("PropertyPhotoUrls")]
    public virtual REOProperty REOProperty { get; set; }

    public Guid PropertyPhotoUrlId { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
}
```